# Python Append Function and List

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to crawl and scrape urls from a nested XML sitemap using Python and beautiful soup.

I believe I got the first part down. I've built a simple loop to access the main XML sitemap and pull a list of XML's that match a certain criteria. Then it stores that index of XML's in a list.

The next part is where it gets fuzzy.

I'm trying to loop through each item from the above list and pull out each URL and append the output to a new list that will be written to a text file.

Here's my code for this section:

[image]

When I loop through and build the list I'm getting a weird output:
[image]

My first thought is Python is appending '/n' after each line break. But when I try to loop through the URLs I get this:
[image]

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Please read [ask] and make sure you question has a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Somehow python did not interpret \n as a newline character in this case (maybe cause by the marshalling of the XML contents). That's why it is not a legit URL and you got that error from requests.

A workaround would be to do a `string.split("\\n")` to get back the URLs into a list.

Comment: Thank you so much I will give that a try.